# How can I display the current row index with ng-grid on angular?

Tags: angularjs, indexing, row, ng-grid

This is my columnDef

```
$scope.communityColDef = [{ field: 'name', displayName: 'Name' },
                          { field: 'description', displayName: 'Description' }];
```

I do not have an index number in my data, but when displaying it in a grid I want to display it with a row number.
There was an option to set row number in jqGrid, but I cannot find a similar feature in angularJS.

Answer (score 2):

Okay I found a way to do this but it has multiple problems.  Firstly it is only visual, this means that I do not explicitly set field data or alter your items in a way that the previous answer does. Additionally I do not know how my solution interacts with different sorting or other ngTable functions.

Here is the code :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                     {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                     {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                     {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                     {name: "Enos", age: 34}];  
    $scope.gridOptions = { 
        data: 'myData',
        columnDefs: [
        {displayName:'#', cellTemplate: '<div>{{$parent.$index + 1}}</div>'},
        {field: 'name', displayName: 'Name'},
        {field:'age', displayName:'Age'}]
    };
});
```

This is a purely cosmetic solution, row numbers are added in a new column all the way on the left similar to how it works in jquery. This has the advantage that you don't have to alter your data or items just to enable a row number but comes with the problems I mentioned before.

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/RzjgbggnDrDt37oBblNB?p=preview) ia a plnkr displaying my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Before setting data to grid option add index inside your data json.

**CODE**

```
$scope.communityColDef = [{
    field: 'index',
    displayName: 'Sr. Number'
}, {
    field: 'name',
    displayName: 'Name'
}, {
    field: 'description',
    displayName: 'Description'
}];

$scope.items = data;
//adding index for showing serial number
angular.forEach($scope.items, function(item, index) {
    item.index = index + 1;
});
$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = $scope.communityColDef;
$scope.gridOptions.data = $scope.items;
```

Hope this may help you.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use row.rowIndex in you cell template. I modified the above [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VhMzCSZqRw5TLAhF2hPn?p=preview)

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                     {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                     {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                     {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                     {name: "Enos", age: 34}];  
    $scope.gridOptions = { 
        data: 'myData',
        columnDefs: [
        {displayName:'#', cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText" data-ng-class="col.colIndex()"><span>{{row.rowIndex + 1}}</span></div>'},
        {field: 'name', displayName: 'Name'},
        {field:'age', displayName:'Age'}]
    };
});
```